# HTML link that includes a span and image not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, cursor

I have the following problem. When I make an `<a>` link and include into it an `<img>` and a `<span>` with text, it works fine as a link, but the cursor is doing strange things. I think it's a CSS problem.

When I hover over the .image or .desc, sometimes the pointer cursor disappears, sometimes not.

```
<a href="#">
   <span class="image">
      <img src="url" />
   </span>
   <span class="desc">
      Some text
   </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a { float: left; display: table; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; }
.image { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; cursor: pointer; }
.image img { position: absolute; ....)
.desc { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; position: relative; cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: why are you changing cursor in css in the first place?
By default it changes to "pointer" when you hover over a link..
And if you copy&pasted that css then .image img is closed with a parenthese ")" instead of a closing bracket "}"

Comment: Quick semantics tip: use <figure> and <figcaption> for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange markup here. I think, you're don't need for `display: table` and `display: table-cell` with `absolute` positioning image inside. Maybe if you simplify your markup, that strange behaviour disapears.

Comment: This is because I need this link responsive with fixed image width... I didn't copy whole CSS here